# Can I re-initialize a disk changing between MBR/GPT without losing data?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery, mbr, gpt

A Windows 10 PC started today with a black screen *"Preparing automatic repair"* on loop. Then somehow Windows started but one HDD was missing.

From *Disk Management* I can see the HDD, but as an *Uninitialized disk* (without space allocated or not).
I'm trying several software solutions to recover data (like MiniTool Power Data Recovery, EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard), but they can't see the disk or its partitions, or they crash.

The options I seem to have are **Initialize the disk** or **Rebuild MBR** and the try and recover the data. The problem is that *I don't know if the disk is MBR or GPT*.

1. *Is there a way to know if a disk not initialized was MBR or GPT?*
2. ***Can I initialize an MBR disk with data as GPT** or viceversa and still recover (or don't lose) the data?*

Comment: to tell if the disk is mbr or gpt, you can open command prompt, type `diskpart` then type `list disk`. The last column will have an asterisk in the GPT column if the disk is gpt and nothing if it is not. With windows tools, there is no way to convert without data loss. There are third party tools which let you convert without data loss though.

Comment: If you initialize the disk you will lose your data

Comment: `diskpart` shows it, but as if there's no data (0 bytes, etc.), so I'm not sure that the asterisk missing is enough, or if it's missing because it can't be read

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If your goal is to recover data Then your first question should be “what happened” or “what is wrong” with your hard drive. If you ask me, it sounds like your hard drive has suffered a catastrophic failure. Sounds like it is a firmware issue. At this point only a data recovery company can get your data back. Good news is, you probably can’t make it any worse because it will be impossible for you to write to the disk. Which is why everything crashes or gives erroneous info, such as disk size.

Comment: @ Hodor, you can see free size and GPT label to know the usage size and if it's GPT or MBR like this:https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avq27-O7I1GRgxHOqT_MXF92RR2A

Comment: Thanks @Appleoddity, I followed your advice and made a new post: https://superuser.com/q/1311496/891264